# How to customized Django filter by adding a custom choice?

Tags: python, django, listview, filter, django-filter

```
### models.py
class pro(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('hi', 'hi'),
        ('bye', 'bye'),
        ('yo', 'yo'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

### views.py
import django_filters

class customfilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # insert some code here
    class Meta:
        model = pro
        fields = ['status',]
class proview(FilterView):
    template_name="1.html"
    filterset_class = customfilter


###1.html

 <form action="" method="get">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

---

how to let the dropdown in template render the choice like this?  *So that the fourth option will make the filter choose all the pro objects that have a hi or bye status*

('hi')
('bye')
('yo')
('hi or bye")

---

Comment: for choices, django has a field choices, check it out here with example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices